# Set response status before render in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'd like to set the response status value in particular action methods before the render method is called. Is this not possible?

Many of my methods in controllers render JSON API views for action methods like #destroy, #update, #create and those actions simply invoke #show or #index as is appropriate. However, I'd like to also return the appropriate HTTP Response status value, like 201, 202, etc, without having to pass arguments to these methods. Essentially, I am looking for something like this:

```
  def destroy
    # code that kills
    status :accepted # ArgumentError, status= silently fails
    index
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

if you just call

```
response.status = ###
```

in a controller, and then don't add the `:status` argument at `render`, it should get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the method render by passing the parameter :status, example :

```
render nothing: true, status: 201
```